# How to configure Push Notifications on Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I have deployed a Parse Server on Heroku and mongoDb using a modified fork of the parse-server-example on GitHub. I have looked at the wiki here on how to send push notifications on parse server: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push
but I am looking for a more in-depth response. My **CLOUD CODE (cloud/main.js)** to send a scheduled push notification (which functioned properly on the hosted version of Parse) is

```
    Parse.Cloud.define('sendPush', function(request, response) {


    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.equalTo('username', request.params.targetUsername);


    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.matchesQuery('user', userQuery);


   Parse.Push.send({
   where: pushQuery,
     data: {
        alert: 'You have a new message from ' + request.params.fromUsername + '!'
      }, 
      push_time: request.params.date
    }, {
      success: function() {
        // Push was successful
        response.success('push successful')
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // Handle error
        response.error('push failed')
      }
   });

    });
```

I am working strictly with iOS and I am looking to have this code function again on my Parse Server. The wiki guide says I need to configure the Parse server, which I am not sure how to do or where to do it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the parse-server wiki:

```
 var server = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: '...',
    cloud: '...',
    appId: '...',
    masterKey: '...',
    push: {
      android: {
        senderId: '...',
        apiKey: '...'
      },
      ios: {
        pfx: '/file/path/to/XXX.p12',
        bundleId: '',
        production: false
      }
    }
  });
```

So you just put everything in there inside your main.js.

You can also find a really comprehensive guide for setting up push notifications on parse-server here:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Configuring-a-Parse-Server

Comment: I tried putting that inside my main.js but inside of a cloud code function. That might have been the problem.

Comment: glad you were able to fix it :)

Comment: What belongs in the 'cloud' field?

Comment: Documentation says:  "Absolute path to your Cloud Code" so it's the path to your cloud code directory. Since you are using parse-server-example and Heroku, the path should already be correct: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js' as long as you put your clode code in the directory named "cloud".

Answer (score 2):

Its easy you just need to put your push notification keys in the parse config. In your index.js file just add push object to new ParseServer initialization like this:

```
var server = new ParseServer({
    push: {
      android: {
        senderId: 'your send id',
        apiKey: 'your app key'
      },
      ios: {
        pfx: 'path to pfx local',
        bundleId: '',
        production: false
      }
    },
    databaseURI: 'your database uri',
    appId: 'your app key',
    masterKey: 'master key',
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you start your `parse-server`. If you start it directly on the command line, you can do:

```
parse-server myConfig.json
```

The server entire configuration goes into this myConfig.json file, for push and for other aspects of your server. Here is an example content of `myConfig.json`

```
{
   "appId": "APP-ID",
   "masterKey": "MMASTER-KEY",
   "cloud": "relative-path-to-directory-that-contains/main.js",
   "push": {
      "ios":{
         "pfx": "relative-path-to-apple-push-cert.p12",
         "bundleId": "com.company.appname",
         "production": false
      },
      "android":{
         "senderId": "your-gcm-sender-id",
         "apiKey": "your-api-key"
      }
   }
}
```

If you start your parse-server from express or from some node script, the answer is similar to others have said, except that the paths have to be absolute paths:

```
var server = ParseServer({
   "appId": "APP-ID",
   "masterKey": "MMASTER-KEY",
   "cloud": "absolute-path-to-directory-that-contains/main.js",
   "push": {
      "ios":{
         "pfx": "absolute-path-to-apple-push-cert.p12",
         "bundleId": "com.company.appname",
         "production": false
      },
      "android":{
         "senderId": "your-gcm-sender-id",
         "apiKey": "your-api-key"
      }
   }
})
```

It's been 3 months since you asked this question so you probably have gotten over the initial confusion of setting up a `parse-server`. If you still have questions, it may help to go through the exercise of setting up `parse-server` on your local machine so you know exactly where's where and what's what.

Here is a [guide to setup parse-server for local development](http://taivo.github.io/guides/parse-server-for-local-development).

Comment: Hello, please how can i get the absolute path for the main.js in and how can i get the cloud directory as well. @lastoneisbearfood

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your parse-server with the necessary key for push notification

Visit https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push to learn how to achieve this.

Comment: I have seen that, but my question is how I configure my parse server with those keys? Where do they go?

Comment: You set them where the Parse Server instance is created eg:`var api = new ParseServer({..});` This is in the `index.js`of the parse-server-example

Comment: this is why you are not suppose to just leave a link, and should at least write the main points of the link ...